# One vm on load balancer is receiving higher traffic when mirrored via nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, f5

Our existing live application is a web service, running on On-Prem and its configured with f5 load balancing pool. Application service is exposed in 10200 port in all host members. Now we are introducing Nginx reverse proxy on same host members which is exposed in 80 port so all live traffic goes through nginx 80 port and same routed to upstream application port 10200 ( on same host localhost:10200 ). We wanted to enable 80 port on only one host member in pool to test the traffic and flow before we completely enable all host members with 80 port in the pool. We did a canary deployment and opened up one host alone which will receive the on-prem traffic. So both the application port(10200) and ngnix port(80) is exposed and we noticed that the number of requests are higher on this node alone and the other members on the load balancing pool are receiving significantly lesser traffic. But when we disable the application port(10200), requests are split equally. I want to understand whether this is the behaviour of the Load balancer or the nginx component and why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This starts to sound like a persistence issue due to the reverse proxy and lb method.

If you're persistence policy is via source IP then it might want to keep putting new sessions on the same pool member because it sees the same IP coming into the app service 10200.

What is the persistence method, protocol profile (TCP/HTTP?) and what is the LB method for the incoming traffic?  I can update this answer with more details.

Comment: Both default and fallback Persistence profile is none. LB method is round robin and the protocol is HTTPS.